# Need help with 熊 pronunciation

Tags: kanji, readings, rendaku

Sorry if this question have already been asked but I did some research and didn't find anything about this.

So I just started to learn some kanji and I decided to look around at names with kanji just to see what it's like. So I went and researched some names from a game and I came across this:

> 星熊　勇儀

And the name is supposed to be read like this:

> ほしぐま　ゆうぎ

I just don't understand why the kanji 熊 is “くま” but is read “ぐま”.

Thanks for any information you have!

Comment: Nimuki, definitely read the post that istrasci linked to.  The phonetic rules for compounds often dictate that the second element becomes voiced: `/k/` become `/g/`, `/s/` becomes `/z/`, `/t/` becomes `/d/`, etc.  This is called 連濁{れんだく}, literally "linked muddiness", as in "the sound becomes muddy (= less distinct = voiced) when terms are linked together".

Comment: Thanks guys ill be sure to read that,i didnt know that there was such a rule :)